# Create circle coordinates given central lat/long and radius

Tags: c#

I'm creating an application to create a circle of any radius given a central lat/lon coordinate. What I need to do is take the initial lat/lon coordinates and radius and calculate the points for the circle and add them to a dictionary list.

Here's what I have so far, but wit this, I get an error saying that 'An item with the same key has already been added' which leads me believe that it isn't actually converting the circle coordinates correctly.

```
private const double EARTH_RADIUS_NM = 3437.670013352;

private void plot(double lat, double lon, double radius)
{
    var coords = new Dictionary<double, double>();

    lat = ConvertToRadians(lat);
    lon = ConvertToRadians(lon);
    double d = radius / EARTH_RADIUS_NM;
    for(int x = 0; x <= 360; x++)
    {
        double brng = ConvertToRadians(x);
        var latRadians = Math.Asin(Math.Sin(lat) * Math.Cos(d) + Math.Cos(lat) * Math.Sin(d) * Math.Cos(brng));
        var lngRadians = lon + Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(brng) * Math.Sin(d) * Math.Cos(lat), Math.Cos(d) - Math.Sin(lat) * Math.Sin(latRadians));

        coords.Add(latRadians, lngRadians);
    }
}

public double ConvertToRadians(double angle)
{
    return (angle * Math.PI) / 180;
}
```

Example of use:

```
plot(33.9331486, -118.4320114, 0.5);
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What line is the error being thrown on?

Comment: @krillgar  `coords.Add(latRadians, lngRadians);`

Comment: Why is this a dictionary? Surely it should be a list of points so you can plot a circle?

Comment: are you sure this algorithm is correct? it only seems to be plotting near the origin. It's like it's missing a lat,lon offset

Comment: http://www.plux.co.uk/converting-radians-in-degrees-latitude-and-longitude/ have to convert from radians back to degrees before plotting. problem solved

Comment: May I know any reference of this algorithm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are entering the coordinates correctly. The problem is that a `Dictionary` is not the correct data type to be using for your data storage. A circle will always hit the same X coordinate in the positive and negative heights over your y-axis.

You'll want to create a simple class to store the two coordinates, and make a List of them:

```
public class Coordinate 
{
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lon { get; set; }

    public Coordinate(double lat, double lon) 
    {
        this.Lat = lat;
        this.Lon = lon;
    }
}
```

Then inside your method, have `var coords = new List<Coord>();`. Then where you're currently assigning them now, just do the following:

```
coords.Add(new Coordinate(lat, lon));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a `Dictionary<,>` since it will not allow two points with the same 1st coordinate.

Use instead something like `List<Tuple<double, double>>` or `List<Point>`.